# Teradata Substring fetch

Tags: substring, teradata

I have data in a column which goes like this:
  **Phone:Yes,Mail:No,Email:Yes,SMS/MMS:No**
I also have columns named **Phone, Mail, Email, SMS/MMS**

How can i extract the field values(Yes/No) and load the appropriate columns however order they appear ? (As an eg : **Mail:No,Email:Yes,Phone:Yes,SMS/MMS:No**)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a function for extracting values from Name-Value-Pairs:

```
NVP(col, 'Mail', ',', ':')

NVP(col, 'Mail', -- name
                 ',', -- name delimiter
                      ':') -- value delimiter
```

Comment: NVP is what should have been implemented when query bands first arrived. :)

Comment: Well, there was GetQueryBandValue :-)